# Python asyncio で非同期にしたプログラムでwas never awaitedとエラーが出る。

Tags: python, python3, 非同期

Pythonバージョンは3.7.3です。
Pythonの非同期処理について勉強するためスクリプトを書いているのですが、

実行すると下記のエラーが出力されます。

```
lyrics.py:75: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Lyric.lyric_from_genius.<locals>.main_loop.<locals>.get_lyric_soup' was never awaited
  self.__gtask += [get_lyric_soup(url)]
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

待つ処理は入れているはずなのですが、なぜエラーになるのかわかりません。
詳しい方お力を貸して頂けないのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

```
import asyncio
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


#Lyrics__Container-sc-1ynbvzw-2

class Lyric():
    def __init__(self, artist, song_name, max_recur=3):
        self.artist = artist
        self.song_name = song_name
        self.__gtask = []
        self.__canceled = False
        self.__lyric = ''
        #何回再帰的に行うか。リクエスト5と再帰3で合計15回までリクエストを投げる。
        self.__max_recur = max_recur
        self.genius_url = self.make_genius_url(artist, song_name)
        lyric = self.lyric_from_genius(self.genius_url, self.__max_recur)
        print(lyric)
    
    def make_genius_url(self, artist, song_name):
        search_song = f'{artist} {song_name}'
        search_song = search_song.replace(' ', '-')
        print(search_song)
        return f'https://genius.com/{search_song}-lyrics'
    

    def get_soup(self, url):
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
            return soup
        else:
            return False
    
    def scrape_genius(self, url):
        if not self.__canceled:
            soup = self.get_soup(url)
        if soup and not self.__canceled:
            lyric_soup = soup.select('.song_body-lyrics .lyrics p')
            if lyric_soup:
                self.__canceled = True
                tags = lyric_soup[0].find_all(['a', 'i'])
                for tag in tags:
                    tag.unwrap()
                print('ここから歌詞です。')
                print(lyric_soup[0].text)
                self.__lyric = lyric_soup[0].text
                self.__gtask.cancel()
            else:
                print('歌詞情報を取得出来なかった。')
        else:
            if self.__canceled:
                print('歌詞取得した')
            else:
                print('歌詞情報がない')
            self.__gtask.cancel()



    def lyric_from_genius(self, url, depth):
        print('再帰の回数確認depth: ', self.__max_recur - depth)

        async def main_loop(url):
            async def get_lyric_soup(url):
                await self.loop.run_in_executor(None, self.scrape_genius, url)
            
            #main_loopの処理       
            for _ in range(1):#同時にリクエスト投げる数を調整する。
                self.__gtask += [get_lyric_soup(url)]
            
            self.__gtask = asyncio.gather(*self.__gtask)
            return await self.__gtask
        try:
            self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            self.loop.run_until_complete(main_loop(url))
        except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
            print("*** CancelledError ***", e)
        finally:
            if self.__lyric or depth <= 0:
                return self.__lyric
            else:
                print('１回のリクエストで曲情報が取れなかった。')
                return self.lyric_from_genius(url, depth - 1)
        
        


Lyric = Lyric('kamal', 'blue')
```

**追記**
エラーが出るのは歌詞情報が１回目のイベントループで取得出来ずに再帰処理で2回目の処理に移った際に出ます。

**追記2 await追加**
確かにawaitをたくさん入れたらエラーは出なくなったのですが今度、曲情報を追加した際のタスクをキャンセルする処理`self.__gtask.cancel()`が上手く行かなくなった気がします。
あとすいません、なぜここまでawaitが必要なのでしょうか？

```
        try:
            self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            self.loop.run_until_complete(main_loop(url))
        except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
            print("*** CancelledError ***", e)
```

コメントの指摘による、修正箇所

```
            #main_loopの処理       
            for _ in range(1):#同時にリクエスト投げる数を調整する。
                self.__gtask += [await get_lyric_soup(url)]
            
            self.__gtask = asyncio.gather(*self.__gtask)
            return await self.__gtask
```

**追記3**
なんでか全くわからないのですがmain loopの中身を下記のように記述する事で上手く動作しています。
どうしてか教えてくださるととても助かります。

```
            #main_loopの処理
            tasks = [get_lyric_soup(url) for _ in range(1)]
            self.__gtask = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            return await self.__gtask
```

Comment: 最初はおそらく歌詞が一回のループで取得出来るのでエラーは出ないと思いますが、何度か実行するとエラーが出ると思います。

Comment: 情報不足でした。すいません。エラー条件を追記しました。

Comment: @metropolis さんの指摘に加えて、その上の`self.__gtask += [get_lyric_soup(url)]`にも`await`を加えて`self.__gtask += [await get_lyric_soup(url)]`にする必要があるようです。

Comment: 修正したのですが、途中で歌詞を見つけた際、`cancel()`で処理を止めているのですが、エラーが上がらなくなりました。

Comment: 先ほど、そこに気づいて修正しました。

Comment: 私も後になってから気が付きましたけど、結局の所、`self.__gtask` を変更(上書き)していた事が原因ということでしょうね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました。